# Inequalities related to ceil function

Tags: asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I need to find a function say $g(x)$ that upper bounds another function say $f(x)$; On that same note suppose $f(x)$ is a ceil function I am acquainted with the inequality that holds for ceil functions i.e:

$$x \leq \lceil x\rceil \lt x+1$$

considering the question as I am interested in the upper bound of the function $f(x)$ (here $\lceil x\rceil$) the right side of the inequality works for me $[\lceil x\rceil < x+1]$ but if I were to multiply a constant c on both sides right off the bat I can see $[c\times\lceil x\rceil \leq c\times(x+1)]$ when $c\geq 0$

Is the above inequality valid for ceil functions? (for any $c$ other than $0$)

Also, if the above is true then is :

$c\times \log \lceil x\rceil \leq c\times\log(x+1)$ , also true

P.S: I am pretty new to this site, apologies for not using correct notations.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to the ceiling function at all. You are just asking if we have $a\lt b$ whether $ca\lt cb$ and $c\log{(a)}\lt c\log{(b)}$ hold. But these are both true when $a,b,c\gt0$.

Comment: a is ceiling function here, also < definitely holds how'd I prove <= holds true?

Comment: More Importantly, my question was for a monotonically increasing function does f(⌈x⌉) ≤ f(x+1) hold true?